# Program crashing only when not run through gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I asked a question earlier about this program and was able to resolve it--the good news is my program is working now!  The bad news is that it only works when I run it through gdb. Whenever I normally compile the program it'll crash, but running it through gdb gives correct output and allows it to exit normally.

I read Dennis Yurichev's post on debugging this sort of problem with the stack or something in gdb, but I'm still pretty new to programming so I have no idea what I am doing.

Here is the output from attaching gdb to the process ID of the program and then dumping the stack:

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x74337480 in OutputDebugStringA () from C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll
(gdb) bt
#0  0x74337480 in OutputDebugStringA () from C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll
#1  0x77478a64 in msvcrt!_invalid_parameter () from C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
#2  0x77425a20 in wctype () from C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
#3  0x00010001 in ?? ()
#4  0x77493a09 in msvcrt!fscanf_s () from C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
#5  0x7749399b in msvcrt!fscanf () from C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
#6  0x00401d0d in main () at ZigSort.c:377
```

I think it's saying it's crashing due to invalid input or something from fscanf, but that doesn't make sense...
The line referenced (main() line 377) is the first fscanf in here:

```
int main(void)
{
    //initializing file pointer
    FILE * ifp;
    ifp = fopen("zigzag.txt", "r");
    int n;

    //getting number of values
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &n); //**LINE 377 RIGHT HERE**

    //reading values into a queue
    queue_t * data = queue_create();
    int ipt;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        fscanf(ifp, "%d", &ipt);
        queue_enqueue(data, ipt);
    }

    //creating a stack of queues
    run_stack_t * runstack = run_stack_create();
    queue_t * run = queue_create();

    //finding runs and pushing them onto the stack
    int runs = 0;
    int *runpoint = &runs;
    while(queue_is_empty(data) != 1)
    {
        run = extract_next_run(data);
        run_stack_push(runstack, run);
        *runpoint += 1;
        optimizestack(runstack, runpoint);
    }

    //merging queues together in sorted order
    data = run_stack_pop(runstack);
    queue_t * merger;
    runs -= 1;

    for(int i=0; i<runs; i++)
    {
        merger = run_stack_pop(runstack);
        data = merge(merger, data);
    }
    queue_destroy(merger);

    //output
    printqueue(data);

    //freeing memory
    queue_destroy(data);
    //run_stack_destroy(runstack, runpoint);
    free(runstack);
    free(runpoint);
    fclose(ifp);
}
```

and the zigzag.txt file that is read in is here:

```
10
9 8 7 6 8 4 2 3 2 1
```

I'm happy to try anything or include any other information that may be necessary, I'm just not sure how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `fopen` can fail. You should take care about it.

Comment: The working directory may not be the same.

Comment: Try running it through something like valgrind? That'll identify any places where you're doing silly things with memory

Comment: Your code lacks of error handling. Of course you get UB results.

Comment: it's a school assignment, I know the text file will be called zigzag.txt and it will be in the same working directory.  I'm not sure why fopen would be failing if zigzag.txt is in the same working directory.  I'm on windows but I'll see if I can run it through valgrind later.

Comment: if fopen fails, then fscanf will fail eventually. Make sure you check fopen returns a valid result.

Comment: In gdb, type `up` until you get to main, then `print ifp`.  What value is displayed?

Comment: with out even looking at the source code, the problem description is (almost) always because the program has some undefined behavior..

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11)   The posted code does not compile, the compiler outputs several messages, including a number `error` messages.  How did you ever get it to run, when it will not successfuly pass through the compiler?  BTW: include the `#include` statements so we do not have guess which header files your program uses.